# How to loop through numeric values (numbers) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have a variable like this:

```
const numbers = 1234567654321;
```

How do I loop through each number here?

I'm so mad I can't find an answer on google for such an easy subject.

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```js
const numbers = 1234567654321;
const str = numbers.toString();
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
  results.push(+str[i]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: What is problem in current code? Just loop through results array and you will get each digit

Comment: why is there "+" in `results.push(+str[i]);` ?

Comment: @MShoaibQureshi `+` here acts as unary plus. It converts anything to number. Same as `Number`

Comment: right right I have used this plus many a times but forgot..Thanks for reminding...
But the fact that these were already numbers. I think there was no need to convert to string, and then back again to numbers.

Comment: @MShoaibQureshi He want each digit separately.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works correctly. There's only one problem which is the loop condition which should be `i < str.length`

```js
const numbers = 1234567654321;

const str = numbers.toString();
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  results.push(+str[i]);
}

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer seems to work (except for the wrong index, like mentioned by Rifat Bin Reza).

You could also use `split()` instead of the for-loop:

```js
const numbers = 1234567890;
const result = numbers.toString().split('').map(num => parseInt(num));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, except for cheking condition `i<= str.length` should be `i < str.length`.
Another approach using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const number = 12345;
const solution = [...`${number}`].map(number => +number);
console.log(solution);
```